# How to convert ListBox.items to string of array collection in c#

Tags: c#, casting, listbox

I have bound array as datasource for ListBox . Now i need to convert listbox.Items to string of array collection.

```
foreach (string s1 in listBoxPart.Items)
{
   clist.Add(s1);
}
```

here clist is string list, so how can i add ListBox.items to clist?

Comment: What does the array contain that you've used as datasource?

Comment: which having both integer and string values . i need answer in c#.net

Answer (score 23):

You can project any `string` contained inside `Items` using `OfType`. This means that any element inside the `ObjectCollection` which is actually a `string`, would be selected:

```
string[] clist = listBoxPart.Items.OfType<string>().ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response .   As per code clist is List<string> and i can't able to use ListBox.Items.OfType(...) . which indicates reference missing . please specify any solution for this that would be more helpfull.

Comment: @user Add `using System.Linq`

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int a = 0; a < listBoxPart.Items.Count; a++)
    clist.Add(listBoxPart.Items[a].ToString());
```

This should work if the items saved in the list are actualy strings, if they are objects you need to cast them and then use whatever you need to get strings out of them

Comment: Thanks for your response. due to performance issue i can't use for loop for this case. can you able to provide solution in foreach loop

Comment: there is almost no performance difference between for and foreach, in almost all cases for is faster then foreach

Answer (score 2):

Just create a list of strings and then add the item.toString() to it.

```
var list = new List<string>();

foreach (var item in Listbox1.Items)
{
    list.Add(item.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the array which is the datasource contains strings:

```
clist.AddRange(listBoxPart.Items.Cast<string>());
```

or if the `DataSource` is a `String[]` or `List<string>`:

```
clist.AddRange((Ilist<string>)listBoxPart.DataSource);
```

if this is actually ASP.NET:

```
clist.AddRange(listBoxPart.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Select(li => li.Text));
```